# Corrupted system_auth keyspace

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster with 6 nodes. As the official documents suggested, we need to change the replication factor of the `system_auth` keyspace to be the same as the number of nodes.

Now the system_auth seems corrupt because there are many version of `system_auth`, as the following:
[image: Different version of system_auth data]

Some of the users could not be altered since I got null pointer exception:
[image: Alter user got Null Pointer Exception]

I tried to use `nodetool repair` to fix it, but didn't help.

Could anyone tell me wha's wrong with my cluster and suggest me how to resolve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running repair with -pr for system_auth across the cluster? Using -pr requires it to be run on every node.

`nodetool repair -pr system_auth`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I followed this post to force Cassandra to rebuild the system_auth Keyspace. If I encounter this error in the future (I hope not :-) ), I will try this solution first and come back here to reply whether it works or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306785/how-to-reset-cassandra-superuser-when-cassandra-does-not-know-cassandra-defau