# InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table credentials"

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm trying to reset the `cassandra` user's password as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398987/how-to-reset-a-lost-cassandra-admin-users-password):

```
UPDATE system_auth.credentials SET salted_hash = '$2a$10$H46haNkcbxlbamyj0OYZr.v4e5L08WTiQ1scrTs9Q3NYy.6B..x4O' WHERE username='cassandra';
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table credentials"
```

My client is cqlsh 5.0.1.

How can I reset the cassandra password?

Cassandra was installed from `datastax-ddc-3.7.0-1.noarch.rpm`

Cassandra version is 3.7.0

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: version is 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Cassandra 2.2  table name changed**
Check the [Cassandra Release News](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8b3a60b9a7dbefeecc06bace617279612ec7092d/NEWS.txt#L533)

**New table is roles**

```
CREATE TABLE system_auth.roles (
    role text PRIMARY KEY,
    can_login boolean,
    is_superuser boolean,
    member_of set<text>,
    salted_hash text
);
```

Use the below query :

```
UPDATE system_auth.roles SET salted_hash = '$2a$10$1PzCxcMNKgsBEcI1lf.ndut24xyO0N2LzRdRF1tzaMaSH9KFLz/0u' WHERE role = 'cassandra';
```

Comment: update query is successful but now unable to log in with password: ```Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to localhost: code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt version"',)})```

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?? I am using cassandra 2.2.4. May be the `salted_hash` value has changed in your version

Comment: 3.7.0. How did you find out the salted hash for your version?

Comment: I have just execute `SELECT * FROM system_auth.roles WHERE role = 'cassandra'`

Comment: Which will give you the `solted_hash`

Comment: I got this hash: `SELECT salted_hash FROM system_auth.roles WHERE role = 'cassandra'  => a0.zmw7dIjd2sN6URl/iOJUNND.EdLXJDK`, yet still getting the same error after updating with the same hash

Comment: It seems that the salt changes with each re-installation? I've gotten new salts: `$2a$10$gNwUkc82ZCl4NR5GPaBkMu0LxjYDHw2.SpdHu6NxIVlX9YuWrmxq2`,

Comment: In the end the following hash worked. Not sure why I was getting the previous ones: `'$2a$10$lvQJJvpW4U7zqVR6xMnzAObShR2EdWcNl3eY9A8cCOi1nIw2gfcU.'`

Answer (score 0):

To change your password use this command:

```
ALTER USER <user_name> WITH PASSWORD <enter_new_password>
```

see http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_user_r.html